# How to automatic filter other dropdown list LARAVEL

Tags: html, mysql, laravel, list, dropdown

Good days. I have the apply form. I want make automatically change other dropdown list when I select some data from previous.

I want add drop down list before code below by name Country. when I change country below university list change automatically. show only selected country university.

```
 <div class="form-group select">
                            <div class="styled-select">
                                <select class="required" name="university_id" required>
                                    <option value="" selected="">Select University</option>
                                    @foreach($universities as $uni)
                                        <option value="{{$uni->id}}">{{$uni->name}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**Full Form code:**

```
    @extends('layouts.index')
@section('main')
    <link href="/assets/css/skins/square/grey.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/css/wizard.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <div id="preloader">
        <div data-loader="circle-side"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Preload -->

    <div id="form_container" class="clearfix">
        <figure>
            <a href="/"><img src="/assets/img/logo/uniwasy.png" width="149" height="42" data-retina="true" alt=""></a>
        </figure>
        <div id="wizard_container">
            <div id="top-wizard">
                <div id="progressbar"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- /top-wizard -->
            <form  action="{{ route('send_admission') }}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <div id="middle-wizard">
                    <div class="step">
                        <div id="intro">
                            <figure><img src="/assets/img/wizard_intro_icon.svg" alt=""></figure>
                            <h1>Apply</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="step">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="full_name" class="form-control required" placeholder="Full name and surname" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control required" placeholder="Your Email" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="styled-select">
                                    <select class="required" name="phone_code"  required>
                                        @foreach($country_codes as $c)
                                            <option value="{{$c->phonecode}}">{{$c->nicename}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group select">
                            <div class="styled-select">
                                <select class="required" name="university_id" required>
                                    <option value="" selected="">Select University</option>
                                    @foreach($universities as $uni)
                                        <option value="{{$uni->id}}">{{$uni->name}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group select">
                            <div class="styled-select">
                                <select class="required" name="area" required>
                                    <option value="" selected="">Select Area</option>
                                    @foreach($areas as $area)
                                        <option value="{{$area->def_name}}">{{$area->def_name}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group select">
                            <div class="styled-select">
                                <select class="required" name="degree" required>
                                    <option value="" selected="">Select Degree</option>
                                    @foreach($levels as $level)
                                        <option value="{{json_decode($level->name)->$lang}}" >{{json_decode($level->name)->$lang}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group select">
                            <div class="styled-select">
                                <select class="required" name="service"  id="service" onchange="updateAgencies()" required>
                                    <option value="" selected="">Select Service</option>
                                    <option value="1" >Basic</option>
                                    <option value="2" >Premium</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group select">
                            <div class="styled-select">
                                <select class="required"  onchange="updateAgencies()" name="city_id" id="city_id" required>
                                    <option value="" selected="" class="select_agency_first">Select Agency Location</option>
                                    @foreach($cities as $city)
                                        <option value="{{$city->id}}" class='city_list city_list_{{ ($city->id==47959) ? 1 : 2 }}' >{{$city->name}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group select">
                            <div class="styled-select">
                                <select class="required" name="agency_id" id="education_apply" required>
                                    <option value="" selected="">Select Agency</option>
                                    {{--
                                      @foreach($agencies as $agency)
                                            <option value="{{$agency->id}}" data-id="{{$agency->id}}" data-city-id={{$agency->city_id}} >{{$agency->name}}</option>
                                       @endforeach
                                       --}}
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /middle-wizard -->
                <div id="bottom-wizard">
                    <button type="submit" name="process" class="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
                <!-- /bottom-wizard -->
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /Wizard container -->
    </div>
    <!-- /Form_container -->

    <!-- Modal terms -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="terms-txt" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="termsLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="termsLabel">Terms and conditions</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in porro albucius qui, in <strong>nec quod novum accumsan</strong>, mei ludus tamquam dolores id. No sit debitis meliore postulant, per ex prompta alterum sanctus, pro ne quod dicunt sensibus.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in porro albucius qui, in nec quod novum accumsan, mei ludus tamquam dolores id. No sit debitis meliore postulant, per ex prompta alterum sanctus, pro ne quod dicunt sensibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>in porro albucius qui</strong>, in nec quod novum accumsan, mei ludus tamquam dolores id. No sit debitis meliore postulant, per ex prompta alterum sanctus, pro ne quod dicunt sensibus.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in porro albucius qui, in nec quod novum accumsan, mei ludus tamquam dolores id. No sit debitis meliore postulant, per ex prompta alterum sanctus, pro ne quod dicunt sensibus.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn_1" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <script>
        function updateAgencies(){
            let service = document.getElementById('service').value;
            
            
            let city_list = document.getElementsByClassName('city_list');
            for(let h=0;h<city_list.length;h++){
                let display_value=( $(city_list[h]).hasClass('city_list_'+service) ) ? 'block' : 'none';
                city_list[h].style.display = display_value;
                
                if(display_value=="none"){
                    $(city_list[h]).prop('selected', false);
                }
            }
            
            let city_id = document.getElementById('city_id').value;
            
            
            let url = '/api/update_agencies';
            $.ajax({
                method:'POST',
                url:url,
                data: {
                    'city_id' : city_id,
                    'service' : service
                }
            })
                .done(updateThem)
            .fail(function(data){
                
            })
        }
        function updateThem(data) {

            // clear the previous data
            /*
            let hide_later = document.getElementsByClassName('hide_later');
            for(let h=0;h<hide_later.length;h++){
                hide_later[h].style.display = 'none';
                // hide_later[h].parentNode.removeChild(hide_later[h]);
            }*/
            let cities = data.data;
            let education_apply = document.getElementById('education_apply');
            
            education_apply.innerHTML="<option value='' selected>Select Agency</option>";
            
            education_apply.value = '';
            for(let i=0;i<cities.length;i++){
                let option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = cities[i].id;
                option.innerText = cities[i].name;
                option.className = 'hide_later';
                education_apply.append(option)
            }
        }

    </script>
@endsection
```

Form photo:
[image]

**Database:**
Table name: universities
[image]

Tabke name: countries
[image]

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

create event on change when change the country selection. then write the ajax for get all university to render university selection.

Comment: Thanks for respond. but i dont know coding. can you write complatety for me?